# Como trabalhar com menu intercambiável?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Estou tentando implementar um menu intercambiável, vejam abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando você clica nos três pauzinhos ele abri um menu vertical no lado direito da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clica nos três pauzinhos ele volta a ficar escondido, mas existe um porém.
Quando ele se encontra em um formato de mobile veja como se comporta a aplicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clica nos três pauzinho ele faz sumir o ícone do Menu tornando a aplicação pouco usual, como pode ver abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1º solução seria tentar deixar o menu a baixo do ícone dos três pauzinho, mas já fiz de tudo e não deu certo.
2º solução seria criar um evento do botão que ao clicar fora ele volte para o ícone dos três pauzinhos, ou criar um botão no próprio menu para volta para o ícone dos três pauzinhos.

Essa é a pagina:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container" >
      <a class="navbar-toggle" (click)="display = true" ><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>

        <p-sidebar [(visible)]="display" position="right">
          <p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}" blockScroll="true" styleClass="ui-sidebar-md"></p-panelMenu>
        </p-sidebar>
  </div>
</div>
```

fiz essa tentativa, mas não deu certo:

```
<div class="ui-g">
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container" >
          <a class="navbar-toggle" (click)="display = true" ><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <p-sidebar [(visible)]="display" position="right">
      <p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}" blockScroll="true" styleClass="ui-sidebar-md"></p-panelMenu>
    </p-sidebar>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Se vc for criar o link no próprio Menu, lembre de só mostra-lo quando a tela tiver no máximo 300 pixels ou algo assim. Vc vai ter que usar @media no CSS para isso. O link de 3 pausinhos e comummente chamado de Menu Hamburger, tem um monte de tutorial por ai sobre isso.

Comment: Obs.: já é pouco usual você clicar nos "três pausinhos" lá na esquerda e o menu vir do outro lado da tela.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo como você fária?